# Setting and retrieving nodejs app parameters

Tags: express

On my recent crusade to understand opensource programs I came across this simple statement

```
if ('development' == app.get('env')){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}
```

I guess app.get is checking environment variables on my machine.
I do i set the environment variable so that the above state is actually true ?

Comment: I think there first `I` in your question is supposed to be a `where`?! You have to set the global variable `NODE_ENV` to either `production`, `development` or whatever you can think of. For more information, please read the following: http://www.hacksparrow.com/running-express-js-in-production-mode.html

Comment: Thanks.. the link answers my question pretty well

Answer (score 0):

Different variables can be passed into the app when started.

For example if starting your node app from the command line.

$ NODE_ENV=production node app.js

// console.log( app.get('env') ) would equal production

$ NODE_ENV=testing node app.js

// console.log( app.get('env') ) would equal testing